# How to get the content of a pinned message discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot in discord.js and I want to get the content of a pinned message.

I know I can use `interaction.channel.messages.fetchPinned().then(pinnedMessages => /* do stuf */ );` to fetch the messages. But if you try to print out the value of `pinnedMessages.content` it will return `undefined`.

The type of `pinnedMessages` is an object, but I do not know how I can get the contents of it.

So, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fetchPinned`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetchPinned) returns a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection) of messages. There are a couple of methods you can use, depending on your needs.

To get the content of the first pinned message, you can use:

```js
let messages = await interaction.channel.messages.fetchPinned()
let firstMessage = messages.first()

console.log(firstMessage.content)
```

To get a pinned message by its ID:

```js
let messages = await interaction.channel.messages.fetchPinned()
let messageById = messages.get('MESSAGE ID HERE')

console.log(messageById.content)
```

If you want to log all pinned messages' content:

```js
let messages = await interaction.channel.messages.fetchPinned()

messages.forEach(msg => {
  console.log(msg.content)
})
```